# You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity when handling comment flags

Tags: support, declined-flags, comment-flags

According to [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) incorrect review comments should be flagged as "Non constructive" or what we now call "No longer needed".

> There's another problem here — that group of people that will always leave those comments there can't really be stopped. But we can remove them as we go:

For some years now we have been monitoring NAA and VLQ posts, flagging posts that are not answers but also flagging posts that have been deleted incorrectly from the LQP review queue together with review comments left under post.

Lately however we are finding that these comment flags are declined.

Here are some examples:

[How to wrap parameter in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160822/how-to-wrap-parameter-in-vs-code/47194318#comment81338371_47194318)

[Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow MySql DB connection open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295123/arithmetic-operation-resulted-in-an-overflow-mysql-db-connection-open/47194016#comment81337506_47194016)

[NodeJS/Express API versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32025904/nodejs-express-api-versioning/47189365#comment81329129_47189365)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47088394/5292302

Maybe you don't want us to flag these since they will get auto-deleted or maybe there is just a lot of miss-clicking going on.

Can you please advise?

**EDIT:** Most of comments have now been deleted, hence the original links do only work for moderator.

Comment: Some of those the mod most likely just didn't think the comment was inappropriate, not that those types of comments shouldn't be flagged when they're inappropriate.

Comment: The term "no longer needed" is the perfect term to use when flagging these comments. I come across answers which have been flagged, hit the queue, receive a comment from a reviewer but then are edited into an answer. These comments are now "no longer needed" and should be removed. It helps to stop robo reviewers from seeing the comment and recommending deletion without looking over the post. A perfect example is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47194016/6375113) which shouldn't have even hit the queue (already in the Q). It should have just been edited. That comment _should_ be removed.

Comment: @Servy if mod consider the review comment correct, they should delete the post. I understand some of the answers are not the best answer, but according to me they still are answer and should not be deleted by LQP review queue, so according to meta comments should be flagged.

Comment: @PetterFriberg They certainly could, but they don't have to.  When they're reviewing comment flags they're reviewing comment flags, and not the posts they're posted under.

Comment: @Bugs Why it shouldn't be in the queue? I think that even after the edit it still should be deleted because it should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: @Servy *hmm that's a mess :)*, how can they evaluate if comment is no longer need?, maybe they would need to check post or otherwise we better stop flagging no longer need for all comments that are related to post (post have been edited etc)

Comment: @Oleg I personally wouldn't flag that as NAA or VLQ just because of the length of it or because of the `??`. I would just edit it up like the last guy did. It's an answer or at least it's an _attempt to answer_. It's not asking a new question, or asking for clarification. It was miss-flagged but that's another story and deviating from the real issue. The point still stands, that comment should be removed.

Comment: @Servy it's only been recently that we have started to be declined for these sort of comments. We've been doing this for some time with no problem. I'm not saying that it's right but we would like to know _why_ we are being declined on what we feel are valid flags. Consider a _this is a link only_ comment on a post that has been edited to show relevant information. That comment should be deleted, why keep it around? It's pure noise and a cleanup would be valid. A mod would know that and yet we are being declined.

Comment: Three of the four of those were declined by a single moderator in a batch. I'll ping them to get their response. I almost always delete those, if the review was indeed wrong or the answer has been updated to address any issues.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm the mod that declined these, apparently. I'm going to admit right off the bat that I only remember one of these questions based on the title. Based on the time of these declines, it looks like these were done when I went through and cleared out about 120ish comment flags this morning.

#### A bit of context

The comment flag queue isn't all that great. We see the flagged comment. If there are multiple comments flagged on the same post, they are grouped together. Other than that, there is no context. We see the comment, the flag reason, a link to the post and the option to accept or decline. Basically, we lack a lot of context without going to each post.

This is fine for the countless flags of "Thanks for the help..." or "Hooray!" or "I fixed this and updated the answer" or the insults (so many insults). It's not great when we actually need context (ie. has a post been updated or who flagged).

For that reason, I try to get rid of the obvious stuff first and then go back through and look at the ones that need context. As I mentioned above, this morning there were a lot of comment flags and not as many "easy" ones as I'd hoped. When I started looking at the context ones, several of the ones flagging old review comments were not "no longer needed".

#### What I need to do differently

One of the things I did when I noticed several of these were invalid is to decline a batch of them. Without the context of who is flagging the comments (there is a user script, but when I use it on SO I get rate limited enough of the time that I have it disabled by default), I assumed that these were all from the same person. This was my mistake.

In the future, when I see these I'll use the userscript for a bit more context. This provides an extra check before I need to go through the full post for each one. This eliminates the assumption I made.

Regarding the comment made by Servy above:

> They certainly could, but they don't have to. When they're reviewing comment flags they're reviewing comment flags, and not the posts they're posted under.

This is correct. When I'm in comment clearing mode, I'm generally not even thinking about removing the post unless there are other flags on it. Dealing with flags on comments and flags on posts requires a bit of context switching.

---

I apologize for the declined flags you received from me for this. Please do keep flagging these comments.

Comment: Thanks Andy, no harm done, keep up your excellent mod work. I just wanted to signal a problem that was occurring lately.